# Calcular diferença entre datas até minutos javascript!

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte data em um input: `25/09/2016 11:20:00` por exemplo.
Preciso calcular a diferença pra data atual e retornar pelo menos ate os minutos. Pode ser em jquery ou javascript. COmo faço?

Answer (score 9):

ja tentou usar o `momentjs`?

http://momentjs.com/docs/

sua usabilidade é bem simples olha alguns ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var data1 = moment('19/08/2013 01:00', "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm");
        var data2 = moment('18/08/2013 21:00', "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm");
        var diferenca = data1.diff(data2, 'hours');

        console.log(diferenca); // 4
 </script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var data1 = moment('19/08/2013 01:00', "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm");
        var data2 = moment('18/08/2013 21:00', "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm");
        var diferenca = data1.diff(data2, 'days');

        console.log(diferenca);
</script>
```

no caso depois de você fazer o data diff você tem q fazer um parse 
basta da uma lida na pagina do moment que tem vários exemplos bons la com o que você necessita.